# Swift Closure to Objective-C block

Tags: objective-c, swift, closures

I have Swift code that reads as below. I want to create an Objective-C code that can accept the closure being passed in `someFunctionThatTakesAClosure` and call it back too.

```
func someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(arr: NSArray, originalClosure: @escaping (NSArray)->Void) -> Void
{

}

func callPrintInput(a: String)
{
    someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(arr: [a],
                                  originalClosure: {
                                    args in let val0 : String = args[0] as! String;
                                    return self.printSomething(a: val0);
    })
}
```

What have I tried:

```
+ (void) acceptClosure: (void (^_Nonnull)(NSArray* arr))closure
```

but this gives error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '(NSArray) -> Void' to expected argument type '([Any]?) -> Void'
```

I know similar questions has been answered many times, but I'm not able to make much progress out of them. Request you to please either explain an answer or help with this question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you use Swift arrays (not explicit NSArray) for your closure they're exposed to Obj-C as NSArray with lightweight generics.

Comment: When I change it to `@escaping (Array<Any>)->Void)` - I get runtime crash `originalClosure ([Any]) -> Swift.Void 0x000000010d1183a0 SwiftTestpartial apply forwarder for SwiftTest.ViewController.(callPrintInput (a : Swift.String) -> ()).(closure #1) at ViewController.swift`

Comment: The `Any` type might be tripping it up (the AnyObject -> Any conversion is rather new). Would be interesting to see if it could handle explicit types.

Comment: Please provide a MCVE, the code you posted is hard to follow and I doubt it even successfully compile.

Comment: What is MCVE? All I need is an Objective-C method that can accept the closure which is written above.